# Не работают тесты JUnit5 в Spring Boot проекте

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Пробую запустить Unit тест в проекте на Spring Boot.
Вот pom.xml

```html
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>

    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>ru.home</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-first-devops</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-first-devops</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>my-first-devops</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <org.springframework-version>5.3.1</org.springframework-version>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>

    <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.8.1</junit.platform.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            --illegal-access=permit
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
```

В корне папки
test
java
находится файл созданный самим Spring

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyFirstDevopsApplicationTests {
//    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

А в папке
test
java
service
Мой класс с тестом

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
class UserServiceTest {
    private UserService userService;
    @Test
    void usersEmptyIfNoUserAdded() {
        var users = userService.getAll();
        assertTrue(users.isEmpty());
    }
}

mvn test
```

не находит ни одного теста.
Если запустить этот класс из IDEA выбрав run UserServiceTest, то выдает ошибку:

```
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
```

Пробовал добавить все зависимости как показано на этом сайте:
[JUnit 5 Maven Dependency](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit5-maven-dependency/)

тогда

```
mvn test
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project my-first-devops: There are test failures.
```

Answer (score -1):

А для чего нужен класс `MyFirstDevopsApplicationTests`? Нужно пометить аннотацией `@SpringBootTest` класс `UserServiceTest`. Также добавить `@Autowired` на поле `userService`

Comment: Ну и что не так с моим комментарием? Я смотрю здесь много умников любящих поминусовать. При этом у самих язык в *опе, ничего написать не могут

Comment: Наверное не так то, что это не комментарий, а ответ.

Comment: извенити, не знал о таких очень важных нюансах